# Liferay portlet does not receive form data

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet

I have made a portlet in Liferay which displays a form. I would like to process the form data after submit, but the data "disappears" somewhere.

This is my form code in jsp:

```
<portlet:actionURL windowState="normal" var="filterURL">
</portlet:actionURL>
    <form action="<portlet:actionURL />" method="post">
    Industry: <input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace />industry" value="<%= industryFilter %>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</form>
```

The data should be passed to my portlet class, but it won't. This is my class code:

```
public void processAction(
        ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
    throws IOException, PortletException {

    String industryFilter = actionRequest.getParameter("industry");
    if(industryFilter == null) {
        industryFilter = "no-param";
    }
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("industry", industryFilter);

    super.processAction(actionRequest, actionResponse);
}
```

This class is intended to pass the data back to the jsp. The `setRenderParameter()` method works fine, as in jsp I can read the value using `request.getParameter("industry");` However, it returns always "no-param", which means, the `actionRequest.getParameter()` return null.

So, it seems my `processAction` methods gets properly called, but it does not receive the form data. Where is the error, what did I wrong?

**Update:**

I downloaded the portlet to my local machine, deployed to a local demo Liferay installation, and it worked! So the code should be ok, it must be some server setting/problem. One difference I realized that in the network tab of the Chrome developer tools, the local server has only one POST call with status 200 while on the remote server there is a POST with 302 Moved Temporarily and a GET 200 with the same URL! Could it cause the problem?

Comment: works for me. Do you have `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>` on your jsp as well? Check if the HTML contains fragments of the `<portlet:*>` tags. The namespacing should be resolved automatically...

Comment: Yes, I have the taglib, the HTML is properly resolved. I also tried `aui:form` and `aui:input` and `ParamUtil` as suggested below, but without success. `actionRequest.getParameterNames()` return an empty set, is this which should store the form values?

Comment: Could it be that you're working on a different portlet than you expect on that remote server? Add some log output, redeploy and check again if the expected log output is coming up. If it doesn't, I'm afraid you'll have to dig deeper into server configuration etc. Are your remote and local Liferay running on the same appserver?

Comment: The other parts of the portlet are working as expected (it lists useres, and I would like to use the form as a filter to narrow the list). Both instances use Tomcat, however, the server runs Linux while my local machine is Windows. I copied the server's portal-ext.properties but it made no difference.

Comment: Please refer to https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-44604 .  (This is already cross-linked from there.  Will try to help drive-forward a resolution on the underlying issue from there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have finally find the solution myself. At some point, I added the portlet to another page, and surprisingly, it worked! So I deleted the original page and re-generated step by step, setting permissions etc. I realized that the problem was the name (friendly URL) of the page! It was set to **members** which seems to caused the problem. I changed it to *alumni-members* at it works now.

Answer (score 6):

You should either put a namespace prefix to your `name` value like this:

```
<input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace />inputTextName" />
```

or you can set the `requires-namespaced-parameters` setting to false in your `liferay-portlet.xml`.

This is a change since Liferay 6.2: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-aui-upgrade-tool/issues/30

Comment: I forgot to mention that this project used Liferay 6.1 CE, but the issue is already solved. Anyway, thank you for your addition!

Comment: Please refer to https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-44604 .  (This is already cross-linked from there.  Will try to help drive-forward a resolution on the underlying issue from there.)

Answer (score 1):

The name of your form element is `"<portlet:namespace />industry"`, not just "industry". Try this line of code instead.

```
String industryFilter = 
    actionRequest.getParameter(actionResponse.getNamespace()+"industry");
```

EDIT:
I wasn't aware that the portlet namespace was stripped from parameters as they come in. I assume this must be a Liferay thing. I'll offer some other options in that case.

If you're still having trouble getting the parameter off the request it may worth doing some debugging. You can use `actionRequest.getParameterMap()` to get all the parameter and see if some odd naming is happening.

Also, consider if you have any filters in between the browser and your portlet that might be manipulating the request. For me, we've had to implement a portlet filter that stripped any parameter that matched a regex for SQL injection attacks and that caused us some problems later that weren't a bit troubling to debug.

Comment: Does someone care to comment on why this answer got a down vote?

Comment: I confess, it was me - I actually wanted to comment that it's wrong, hit the mouse button during scrolling the page (when it was hovering the downvote) and then couldn't undo the downvote (I still can't do, SO says it's locked, the answer needs to be edited to change my vote). The answer is wrong because portlet-namespace is used to disambiguate and is automatically stripped from the parameter name on the java side. Only the HTML side feels clunky (but aui taglibs automatically decorate with the portlet namespace, making the jsp easier to read)

Comment: ↑ Long explanation - sorry. Please edit your answer and I'll try to fight the SO UI again and undo the vote. I typically don't downvote, I feel it's more appropriate to comment. But I also confess that in the struggle against the UI I forgot to comment...

Comment: I tried to debug as you suggested, and tried another way earlier (see my comment to the question), the parameter list is always totally empty. I don't have any filter. The portlet configuration is the default.

Comment: @OlafKock Thanks for coming back to comment. As I stated in the edit, I didn't know Liferay stripped the name space from parameters. Then again I usually only add the namespace to element id's or JS variables so I wouldn't have ran into that before.

Comment: @ttamas If the parameter map is completely empty then I think something else is going on that we can't see from the code you've presented. It should be a fairly simple task to submit form data to a portlet so I can't say there is much else we can do with the question as it is.

Comment: Hm, it's weird, I made a completely new, blank portlet, copied the sample code from Liferay's developer guide, and the result is same: not working. Even if I omit the custom class, and use renderURL instead of action URL. So it seems indeed some more "global" problem. Anyway, thank you for your comments!

Comment: @NickRoth You were right, it should be something else. The portlet works on my local machine. For details, please see the update in the question.

Comment: @NickRoth now I was able to undo. sorry again for the rudeness of not commenting with the accidental vote

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to use liferay's utility methods where ever possible, like:

```
String industryFilter = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "industry");
```

This way you don't have to worry about prepending namespace and moreover [`ParamUtil`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.2-ga3/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/ParamUtil.java) class comes with a number of other helpful methods like `getLong`, `getLongValues` (which return an array of Longs instead of using `request.getParameterValues` and then converting to `Long`), `getInteger`, `getIntegerValues`, ... etc.

Also it would be helpful to use `<aui:input />` tags in the JSP as liferay does:

```
<aui:input type="text" name="industry" value="<%= industryFilter %>" />
```

since that would take care of the namespace in the `name` attribute of the generated html `<input />` tag.

But if you don't want to use any of the above than the solution provided by @NickRoth should work without any issues:

```
String industryFilter = actionRequest.getParameter(actionResponse.getNamespace()+"industry");
```

Comment: I tried every option, but no success. When I check the post-ed data with firebug, I can see the form field properly, with namespace and value, but on server side the actionRequest is not able to return them.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you parameters `<input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace />inputTextName" />`

This will not `<aui:input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace />inputTextName" />`

This will `<aui:input type="text" name="inputTextName" />`